# TwitterApi json doesn't accept arabic and other languages

Tags: java, android, json, android-twitter

Hello I'm working on a Twitter client and when I compose a tweet and post it in arabic or japanese It doesn't accept it. why ?

That's method to post a tweet :

```
public void postTweet(String body, AsyncHttpResponseHandler handler) {
    Log.i(CLASS, "statuses/update.json");
    String apiUrl = getApiUrl("statuses/update.json");
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("status", body);
    getClient().post(apiUrl, params, handler);
}
```

and that's after clicking on send button :

```
  send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TwitterClient client = RestApplication.getRestClient();
            client.postTweet(tweet.getText().toString(), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    Log.e(CLASS, "Error sending the tweet. Status: " + statusCode, error);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error sending the tweet, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

any help please

Comment: Can you show any code or error messages? Put them in your question.

Comment: @ElMaravilla:- Could you please paste your api url?

Comment: @AdarshYadav https://api.twitter.com/1.1

Comment: @ElMaravilla: I tried from twitter api console.It's working fine...what is the error your are receiving in onFailure?

Comment: @ElMaravilla:- I hope you are getting api url something like:- https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json

Comment: @AdarshYadav yes it works fine with english only but when I post a tweet with Arabic it says : org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Authorization Required

Comment: @AdarshYadav It doesn't work with Arabic nor Persian nor Hindi nor Japanese :/ just with English alphabets

Comment: @ElMaravilla:-I am looking into it, I will update you asap I will get any success .

Comment: @AdarshYadav I hope you get it very soon . . Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You should specify charset for it :

try this :

```
ContentType.create("application/json", CharSet.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , but can you tell where I should write it ?